# Understanding how Code works; Shopping Cart Total

Tags: php

I've just begun learning how to create a shopping cart.

Came across this example:

```
<?php

   echo "Shopping cart:\n";

      $items = count($_SESSION['cart']);    
     {
         $total = 0;
    echo "<table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"1\" border=\"1\">\n";
            echo "<tr><td>Item Name</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Total</td></tr>\n";
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemid => $quantity)
            {
                $query = "SELECT description, price FROM items WHERE itemid = $itemid";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
                $name = $row['name'];
                $price = $row['price'];

                $subtotal = $price * $quantity;
                $total += $subtotal;

    printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>$%.2f</td></tr>\n", $name, $quantity, $subtotal);
            }
            printf("<tr><td colspan=\"2\">Total</td><td>$%.2f</td></tr>\n", $total);
            echo "</table>\n";
       }

?>
```

The code works and I understand  most of it except for the "TOTAL or $total" part:

*$subtotal = $price * $quantity;
$total += $subtotal;*

As I said, it does work; if I place two items in the cart, for example: 5 pieces (quantity) of rocks that are $5 each and 2 pieces of pebbles that are $10 each, I get the SUBTOTALS on the respective table-rows of $25 for the widget and $20 for gadget. I'm assuming that

*$SUBTOTAL = $price * $quantity* -----  IS RESPONSIBLE FOR THIS, correct?

What I don't get is how it comes up with the TOTAL (which is correct--$45).

Which part of the code adds up the individual subtotals (i.e. $25 and $20)?

How does **$total += $subtotal**, work?

I'd like to understand how the code works/processes and not just take it because it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$total += $subtotal
```

Is just shorthand for:

```
$total = $total + $subtotal;
```

So to apply it to the code:

```
// Start the total at 0
$total = 0;

// For every item in the cart
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemid => $quantity)
{
    // Get the item's price from the database
    $price = $row['price'];

    // The subtotal is the cost of each item multiplied by how many you're ordering
    $subtotal = $price * $quantity;

    // Add this subtotal to the running total
    $total += $subtotal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think a better question for what I'm trying to understand would be: Which part of the code generates a running total? As you mentioned, --$subtotal = $price * $quantity-- produces subtotals for each individual item ($25 and $20), but how (which part of the code executes $25 PLUS $20) are those subtotals added up to to produce $45?

Comment: I explained it in my post - The `$total += $subtotal` line does it. The `foreach` loop executes twice, once for each item in your cart. The `$total` begins at 0, then 25 is added to it, then 20.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I get it now; the other key component was the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `+=` operator takes the value on the left hand side of the expression, and adds whatever is on the right hand side. Think of it like this:

```
$total = $total + $subtotal;
```

The `foreach()` loops through all items, and in each iteration calculates the total.price for that product by multiplying the product's unit price by it's quantity, which is stored temporarily in `$subtotal`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I initially didn't think that the foreach loop iterated through the $subtotal/$total part. Now I get it.